# Maven shade-plugin relocation not updating a entry in resource file

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, maven-shade-plugin, aws-java-sdk

I am trying shade [aws-java-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) in order to resolve library conflicts as per the recommendation mentioned [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#resolving-dependency-conflicts-with-flink-using-the-maven-shade-plugin). But I see that [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), the entries in resource files (text) are not getting updated. For example contents of the [request.handler2s](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-ec2/src/main/resources/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/request.handler2s) and [request.handlers](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-ec2/src/main/resources/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/request.handlers) are not getting changed as per the relocation pattern.

Can maven-shade-plugin update these files (resource files)? If not what are other options?

The pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.amazonaws</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.XX.YY.shaded.com.amazonaws</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something you could try is adding the ServiceResourceTransformer to your configuration:

```
<transformers>
     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
</transformers>
```

Comment: Try updating the shade-plugin version to 3.0.0, previous versions have known issues with relocating services.

Comment: org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer relocates the files under META-INF/services only. AWS resource.handler files are in different path (com/amazonaws/services/sqs/resource.handler). Has anyone got the solution to change this file during relocation? Facing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @popcoder, Had you got any fix for this issue? struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue in gradle. Too bad it is not as easy to implement a fix inline with maven. Below is the code I added to my build.gradle to allow me to properly shade com.amazonaws:

```
shadowJar {
  zip64 true
  mergeServiceFiles()
  relocate('com.amazonaws', 'shaded.com.amazonaws')
  transform(RelocateAmazonawsServiceRequestHandlers.class)
}

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.Transformer
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.TransformerContext
import shadow.org.apache.tools.zip.ZipOutputStream
import shadow.org.apache.tools.zip.ZipEntry

class RelocateAmazonawsServiceRequestHandlers implements Transformer {
  private Map<String, String> transformedResources = new HashMap<>()

  @Override
  boolean canTransformResource(FileTreeElement fileTreeElement) {
    return (fileTreeElement.getName() ==~ /com\/amazonaws\/services\/.*\/request.handlers/)
  }

  @Override
  void transform(TransformerContext transformerContext) {
    String text = transformerContext.is.text
    transformerContext.relocators.each {
      r -> text = r.applyToSourceContent(text)
    }
    transformedResources.put(transformerContext.path, text)
  }

  @Override
  boolean hasTransformedResource() {
    return transformedResources.size() > 0
  }

  @Override
  void modifyOutputStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) {
    transformedResources.each { key, value ->
      zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(key))
      zipOutputStream.write(value.getBytes())
      zipOutputStream.flush()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you share the full contents of the file? Your piece of code is missing some essentials as the version for example how you imported id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' - what version etc?